# Vue 2 pass value from child to parent element (make custom styled input)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

let say if i have a custom input

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="value"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "my-input",
  props: {
    value: String
  }
}
</script>
```

how i can pass it value to parent element

```html
<template>
  <my-input v-model="test"/>
  <button @click="check">see value</button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    check() {
      console.log(this.test);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

when i press the button it shows `undefined`. i expected it to returns my-input value.

how i could pass value from it? i tried v-model and :value, both shows `undefined`.

Comment: are you using vuex ?

Comment: nope @MohammadBasit

Comment: You need to use emit in vuejs to pass data from child to parent

Comment: 1. What is your `test`? You didn't initial it in the `data`. 2. You are modifing `prop`, and that is something you should not do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the input value to prop `value` then add `@input` event that emits the input value to parent component :

```
<template>
  <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "my-input",
  props: {
    value: String
  }
}
</script>
```